# Solow growth model deriving solutions

Tags: economic-growth, solow

I was reading a note on Solow model in continuous time, and it said we can derive K, C, and Y from the key equation. But the steps were omitted, and I have no clue with it. How can I derive these variables?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: I didn't even attempt to read what I found (I have no formal economics background so a lot of times the language feels quite foreign ) so standard disclaimer applies but I think this link has the method and on page 18 or 19 maybe even the solution.  .https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~vr0j/econ10205/lectures/grow5_solow.pdf